# A method that has a class return type

Tags: java

I don't quite understand how am I going to implement and solve this problem:

> Consider an array data of n numerical values in sorted order and a list of numerical target values (target values are not necessarily sorted). Your goal is to compute the smallest range of array indices that contains all of the target values. If a target value is smaller than data[0], the range should start with -1. If a target value is larger than data[n - 1], the range should end with n.
>
> For example, given the array [ 5 8 10 13 15 20 22 26] and the target values (8, 2, 9, 17), the range is -1 to 5.
>
> 1. Devise an efficient algorithm that solves this problem and implement it in
>
>    ```
>    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
>    Interval findInterval(T[] sortedData, List<T> targetValues)
>    ```
>
>    Where `Interval` is a class that provides two public methods `getLower()` and `getUpper()` to return the lower and upper values of an `Interval` object. Implement the `Interval` class.

I understand the algorithm of the problem. However, I'm confused how I am going to to implement it. Like what would the return value be for the `Interval findInterval` method?

And "Implement the `Interval` class." I don't understand what exactly the `getLower()` and `getUpper()` methods are supposed to return or what type.

I hope someone can give me an idea how I am going to implement this.

Comment: `Internal` will only be a data structure holding the result of your algorithm. The methods `getLower` and `getUpper` shouldn't dynamically compute those values.

Comment: In your example, it says "the range is -1 to 5". That's what the `getLower` and `getUpper` methods on the `Interval` class should be returning, e.g. `-1` and `5` respectively

Comment: @plalx So the getLower and getUpper methods would return the lower and upper range of the Interval object? Would it be a return type of integer?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Okay I understand that part now. However, the implementation of the algorithm would be in the method Interval findInterval itself?

Comment: Yes @aldrich19. `Interval` is just a data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance `Interval` should only be a data structure to hold the result of the calculation. Therefore, `getLower` & `getUpper` will not dynamically perform those calculations.

An example of such data structure may be:

```java
public final class Interval {
   private final int lower;
   private final int upper;

   public Interval(int lower, int upper) {
       // Check preconditions, like lower can't be < -1, etc.
       this.lower = lower;
       this.upper = upper;
   }

   public int getLower() { return lower; }
   public int getUpper() { return upper; }
}
```

I think the most efficient algorithm would be `O(log n + m)` assuming `n` sorted data and `m` target values.

1. First you must find the lowest & highest values in `tagetValues`. This can be done in `O(m)` by keeping a `lowest` & `highest` variables up to date while looping over all the elements.
2. Then you can do 2 subsequent binary searches on `sortedData` to find the lower index from the `lowest` and the highest index from the `highest`. This costs `2 log n` which simplifies to `O(log n)`.

---

[Full implementation example](https://onecompiler.com/java/3xemyzxwz):

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FindInterval {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] data = new Integer[] {5, 8, 10, 13, 15, 20, 22, 26};
    List<Integer> targets = Arrays.asList(8, 2, 9, 17);
    
    Interval interval = findInterval(data, targets);
    
    System.out.println(interval);
  }
  
  public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Interval findInterval(
    T[] sortedData, 
    List<T> targetValues
  ) {
    if (targetValues.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("'targetValues' must not be empty.");
    }
    
    List<T> targetBounds = findTargetBounds(targetValues);

    int lower = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedData, targetBounds.get(0));    
    if (lower < 0 && lower != -1) {
      lower = Math.abs(lower) - 2;
    }
    
    int upper = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedData, targetBounds.get(1));
    if (upper < 0) {
      upper = Math.abs(upper) - 1;
    }
    
    return Interval.of(lower, upper);
  }
  
  private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> findTargetBounds(List<T> targetValues) {
    T lower = targetValues.get(0);
    T upper = targetValues.get(0);
    
    for (T value : targetValues) {
      if (value.compareTo(lower) == -1) lower = value;
      if (value.compareTo(upper) == 1) upper = value;
    }
    
    return Arrays.asList(lower, upper);
  }
  
  private final static class Interval {
    private final int lower;
    private final int upper;
    
    private Interval(int lower, int upper) {
      // Check preconditions, like lower can't be < -1, etc.
      this.lower = lower;
      this.upper = upper;
    }
    
    public int getLower() { return lower; }
    public int getUpper() { return upper; }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "[" + lower + "," + upper + "]";
    }
    
    public static Interval of(int lower, int upper) {
      return new Interval(lower, upper);
    }
  }
    
}
```

Comment: That clears up some of my confusion. So for the method Interval findInterval, the return value would be just like "return Interval(lower, upper)"?

Comment: You'd return `new Internal(lower, upper)` yes. You might want to add a static `of` method to create the interval such as `Interval.of(lower, upper)` which is more readable.

Comment: I wonder what would be the **Big-O** performance of this algorithm? Considering `n` data values in the array and `m` target values in the list.

Comment: @aldrich19 Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This helps me a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that for finding the min/max we could have used `Collections.min()` and `Collections.max()`. We would have traversed `m` twice, but `O(2m)` simplifies to `O(m)` so it wouldn't have changed the complexity.

Comment: Btw, dont forget to accept the answer if it answered all your questions please. That's something that newcomers often forget hehe. Let me know if I can help with anything else for your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, `getLower()` is meant to return the lower range, and `getUpper()` is meant to return the higher range. So for the example given: `getLower() -> -1` and `getUpper() -> 5`.

As for returning a class, you can simply do something like this in your method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
Interval findInterval(T[] sortedData, List<T> targetValues) {
   ...
   return new Interval(...);
}
```

Does this answer your question?